# Can you deploy a contract from a Ledger Nano S using Remix?

Tags: remix, contract-deployment, etherscan, ledger-nano-s, hardware-wallets

I have deployed a contract from a Ledger Nano S before by connecting to MEW and deploying using Bytecode and ABI of the contract.

However I do not know what compiler version MEW used and so cannot verify the contract on etherscan.

I have been able to verify contracts deployed on Rinkeby network using remix and metamask. Metamask automatically connects my wallet to remix to handle the deployment.

IS there a way to do this from a hardware wallet? I would like my wallet address in my ledeger nano s to be the msg.sender but I would also like to be able to verify the contract on etherscan.

Thanks.

Comment: Or if there is a way to verify contract deployed from MEW on etherscan that could work too if anyone knows. Thanks.